# How can I change the ForeColor of the GroupBox text without changing its children ForeColor?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, groupbox

I want to know if there is an option to just change the color of group box text at the top left of the group box in a windows form and not any controls or labels located inside of the group box.

I know that `GroupBox.ForeColor = Color.Blue` will change all text associated with that box to blue, but it also changes the `ForeColor` of labels and other controls in the `GroupBox`.

How can I change the color of the group box text without changing its children forecolor?

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9321720/4934172) question, you'll find several options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The [`ForeColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property is an ambient property. An ambient property is
>   a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent
>   control.

Since you didn't set `ForeColor` for the labels and textboxes in the group box, they will use `ForeColor` value of their parent. You can solve this problem using either of these options:

1. Put a `Panel` in `GroupBox` Set the `ForeColor` of `GroupBox` to `Blue` and set `ForeColor` of `Panel` to `ControlText` explicitly using designer. Then put other controls in the `Panel`. This way, your controls will use `ForeColor` of `Panel` which you set explicitly.
2. Customize `Paint` of `GroupBox`:

   ```
   Private Sub GroupBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Paint

       e.Graphics.Clear(Me.GroupBox1.BackColor)
       GroupBoxRenderer.DrawGroupBox(e.Graphics, Me.GroupBox1.ClientRectangle, _
           Me.GroupBox1.Text, Me.GroupBox1.Font, Color.Blue, _
           System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.GroupBoxState.Normal)
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, all the child controls will take the property of the parent.

You can store all your child colors and change them after you set the GroupBox's ForeColor. You can use a Dictionary with each pair of Control/Color.

Something like:

```
Dim cColors As New Dictionary(Of Control, Color)

For Each ctrl As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
    cColors.Add(ctrl, ctrl.ForeColor)
Next

GroupBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue

For Each ctrl As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
    If cColors.HasKey(ctrl) Then
        ctrl.ForeColor = cColors(ctrl)
    End If
Next
```

You can put that in a method.

More information about the property at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx).